# Displaying Image from data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have read about storing image in database isn't practical, so I stored the image path in Mysql database. How can I display the image in my program? Whenever I tried to set the icon of JLabel, an error said "cannot converted string to icon. What can I do?

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jose", "root", "josehaha");
    Statement stat = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    stat.executeQuery("select img_path from product where ID = 1;");
    ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();
    Object path = rs.getString("img_path");
    jLabel1.setIcon("'" + path + "'");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Consider using [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)...

Answer (score 1):

[`setIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) takes an `Icon` object argument

```
String path = rs.getString("img_path");
....
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
```

Comment: thank you, it fix the error, but i have a question about storing the image path in mysql. i used the datatype varchar for this, and i found out that whenever i save the image path, it trims all the file separator(\\). and i got new problem on retrieving it.

Comment: at a guess I would say there's probably some character escaping going on but it probably deserves a new question...